# MVVM Dynamic DataGrid Sorting Filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, filtering

I have a `DataGrid` that gets its data updated every few seconds via a `Thread`. The `DataGrid` needs to offer Column Header sorting, grouping and filtering.

I currently have a `DataGrid` bound to a `ICollectionView` and the source of the `ICollectionView` is an `ObservableCollection`. Which seems to be the good way to do it from what I read on other threads.

The sort-ing "works" but it gets lost when the `ICollectionView.Source` gets updated following an update of the `ObservableCollection`. I have tried saving the `SortDescriptions` before the update and re-add it to the `ICollectionView` after the update is done. But it's the same result.

May someone point me to what I'm missing?

**Edit Here's some code...**

View (XAML)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}>
```

ViewModel

```
public ICollectionView CollectionView
{
    get
    {
        collectionViewSource.Source = dataColl;
        if (SortDescriptions != null)
        {
            foreach (SortDescription sd in SortDescriptions)
            {
                collectionViewSource.View.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
            }
        }
        collectionViewSource.View.Refresh();
        return collectionViewSource.View;
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<SomeObject> DataColl
{
    get { return dataColl; }
    private set 
    {
        this.dataColl= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CollectionView");
    }
}
```

Following is the method that updates the data every few seconds...

```
private void UpdateData()
{
    while (true)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(mDataRefreshRate);

        // SortDescriptions is a Property of the ViewModel class.
        SortDescriptions = collectionViewSource.View.SortDescriptions;

        ObservableCollection<SomeObject> wDataColl
           = new ObservableCollection<SomeObject>();

        //... Irrelevant code that puts the data in wDataColl ...

        DataColl= wDataColl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some of the source code that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[YourObservableCollection].ViewHandler.View.Filter
                    += new FilterEventHandler(myFilterHandler);

private void myFilterHandler(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Can be used to directly add your filter handler and you can do the same with `SortDescriptions` to Add/Remove

```
[YourObservableCollection].ViewHandler.View.SortDescriptions.Add(mySortDescription);
```

If you are doing allot of sorting and filtering best to create own class encapsulating a CollectionViewSource and implement adding and removing `SortDescriptions` and Filtering etc

When you say:

> The sort "works" but it gets lost when the ICollectionView.Source gets
>   updated following an update of the ObservableCollection

What do you mean by update? you mean you are changing the Source? Rather than adding/removing items from the collection?

**EDIT based on your XAML example you added:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}>
```

You are binding itemsource to the CollectionViewSource where you should bind the datacontext to it:

Example:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myViewSource"
          Source="{Binding CollectionView, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"
    />
</Page.Resources>
```

In page:

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource myViewSource}">

        <DataGrid x:Name="myGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"...
```

Or something along those lines

**EDIT again didnt see code scroll down :p**

```
ObservableCollection<SomeObject> wDataColl= new ObservableCollection<SomeObject>();
```

You create new instance every time of collection lol this is main problem

Also:

```
public ICollectionView CollectionView
{
    get
    {
        collectionViewSource.Source = dataColl;
        if (SortDescriptions != null)
        {
            foreach (SortDescription sd in SortDescriptions)
            {
                collectionViewSource.View.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
            }
        }
        collectionViewSource.View.Refresh();
        return collectionViewSource.View;
    }
}
```

Here where you return collection you are setting the `Source` and adding the `SortDescriptions` and also refreshing the view every time, you only need set these values once

You would only call refresh on the View if you add/remove `SortDescriptions`

I think you should get to grips with basics of [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613527.aspx)

Comment: >What do you mean by update? you mean you are changing the Source? Rather than adding/removing items from the collection?  <br/>

Exactly! Apparently the data does not update unless I reaffect the ICollectionView.Source property to the observablecollection.

Comment: What difference does it make doing this and the way I did it? I followed Niclas recommendation and it works so far...

Comment: >You create new instance every time of collection lol this is main problem  
This is now changed, I use ObservableCollection.Add now

Comment: [DeferRefresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.deferrefresh(v=vs.100).aspx)
may help with performance. It is my new best friend after working with the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you swap out the entire ObservableCollection every time you add new data.

```
    ObservableCollection<SomeObject> wDataColl= new ObservableCollection<SomeObject>();

    ... Unrelevant code that puts the data in wDataColl ...

    DataColl= wDataColl;
```

Make sure to use Add to the existing collection instead (perhaps after using `Clear()` first if that is necessary)... If you still have problems after that please comment and i will try to help.

Also, try to avoid using the `Refresh()` as it rebuilds the entire view and is unnecessarily expensive. If you do sorting, adding, removing etc. the correct way use of Refresh() isn't needed.

Comment: Thx Niclas. It works that way but it seems to have broken the Filtering. I did set a callback the handle ICollectionView filter like this.
myCollectionView.Filter += filterCallback;
When and what should trigger my callback?
I should say... my callback gets call when I sort a column tho...

Comment: You are not doing any filtering in your code. SortDescriptions are used sort the collection, FIlters are used to remove unwanted items that you want/dont want displayed.

Comment: @MarkHomer I did not put the code directly in my example but in my previous comment.  
I do set myCollectionView.Filter += filterCallback; in my ViewModel constructor. But then, when does it get called? Do I have to trigger a refresh?

Comment: @Niclas sorry i directed that comment to ncourcy I should have put the at, sorry new on this site, in there as he was asking about the filter event handler.